# I'm trying to use GLU.gluPerspective(), but it's giving me the static reference error

Tags: java, lwjgl, jogl

Alright. I'm brand new to OpenGL and the things of the like. I'm using LWJGL 3 and JOGL (for GLU) and I'm at a complete stop in my self-learning process. Right now I'm trying to set up my 3D projection using `GLU.gluPerspective(80, 4/3, 0.1, 10000);`, but it's giving me `Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method gluPerspective(double, double, double, double) from the type GLU` - I do know what this means, but I'm not quite sure as to *why* I'm getting this.

I copied/pasted the sample code from LWJGL 3's page to get most of my code. To draw the cube, I use another bit of code I found online.

The code is fairly long so you can get it [at this pastebin link.](http://pastebin.com/nX73qehS)

A bit of a note for the above, lines 158 through 174 use my custom Player class and Keyboard class, which are minimal and have nothing that affects what I'm doing to get my error within them.

So why would this be giving me that error, despite the fact that I instanciated a new `Main()`? Am I just a bit rusty on my memory of Java? (the pastebin code is `Main.java`)

Comment: You mustn't mix JOGL with another Java binding for the OpenGL API, it's not designed to work that way. Either rewrite your code entirely with JOGL if you want to stick with GLU or use the other Java binding without GLU. JOGL has a fundamentally different design: http://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Why_Instance_Design Mixing those both APIs is a very bad idea to me. You can use JOML with those both APIs as it contains some math utilities similar to gluPerspective. JOGL is able to simulate the fixed pipeline too, look at com.jogamp.opengl.util.PMVMatrix and FixedFuncUtil.

Comment: However, you shouldn't use that, it's [deprecated OpenGL](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Legacy_OpenGL)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in the error message `gluPerspective` is not a static method of the class `GLU`, this means you need a `GLU` **object** to call it:

```
GLU glu = new GLU();
glu.gluPerspective(80, 4/3, 0.1, 10000);
```

This is also explained in the [JOGL user guide](https://jogamp.org/jogl/doc/userguide/):

> To use the GLU, simply instantiate a GLU object via new GLU() at the
>   beginning of your program. The methods on the GLU object may be called
>   at any point when an OpenGL context is current. Because the GLU
>   implementation is not thread-safe, one GLU object should be created
>   for each GLEventListener or other entity performing OpenGL rendering
>   in a given thread.

Comment: For clarity, should I have to rewrite most of my code to use GLU or is there a way to use my existing code and link my new GLU object and my existing OpenGL setup?

Edit: I ask because I'm getting "No OpenGL Context on this current thread"

Comment: I'm no expert but I don't think you can mix JOGL with LWJGL. They both are used for the same goal so I think you should choose to use one or the other.

Comment: Okay. That makes a bit more sense. Thanks.

Comment: @LorisSecuro You should use GLU.createGLU(GL) instead of new GLU(), you quoted a document which is still under review.